# Conditional Expressions in Angular's View: What if a model is missing?

Tags: angularjs, view, expression, conditional-statements

Supposed I've in controllers scope

```
$scope.user = {"username": "someUserName"};
```

and as you can see above there is no company information in it.

I want to show alternativ text in the view, if it is missing, like (Pseudo-Code):

```
{{ if "user.company" does not exist show "not set" may be with a certain style }}
```

Is there an Angular way to manage it elegantly?

Something like that would be great:

```
{{ user.company || 'Not set!'.class('danger') }}
```

In this case above I can find `}}` and replace it with `|| 'Not set!'.class('danger') }}`

**I am looking for a generic solution something like: "Show always a certain text with a certain style, if the corresponding model is missing" ?**

Imagine you have to correct these values in 100 different views with different model values. What could you do?

Comment: You can create a custom filter `{{ user.company || customFilter }}`. More information is here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: I think, that would be then the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)**/**[ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)**/**[ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)**

Like this

```
<div ng-if="!user.company">
   Not set
</div>
```

Comment: It is OK, thank you, but better `<span ng-if="..">..</span>`

Comment: it's up to you . I just gave example how can you do that :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more elegant do handle it with an expression.

```
Company:  <div>{{user.company || 'Not Set'}}</div>
```

Comment: however if onbe day you want to animate smth, ng-if will be much better.

Comment: Yes, this is true ^^.  If you wanted to do something special with the div if it was 'Not Set' as opposed to if it had a value.

Answer (score 0):

**ng-if / ng-show / ng-hide should be used.**

```
<div ng-if='!user.company'>Company not set</div>
<div ng-if='user.company'>{{user.company}}</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-hide='user.company'>Company not set</div>
<div ng-show='user.company'>{{user.company}}</div>
```

**Note:**

However if you pretend to change styles if a particular info exists/doesn't exist you can use `ng-class`. Example:

```
<div ng-class='{"no-company": !user.company}'>Company not set</div>
```

Than in css apply your styles:

```
.no-company {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Bottom line:**

- If you want to show text, then use `ng-if` or `ng-show/ng-hide`.
- If you want to change styles or apply effects using classes use `ng-class`.
- Or you can mix the angular directives to achieve more complex results.

Comment: excellent! Is there also a generic solution, something like: "Show always a certain text with a certain style, if the model is missing" ?

Comment: It looks very good, but anyone should consider it during the view-creation process. If you have to correct it afterwards you have too much paper work. What could I do in these cases?